# openerp 7 how to install my own module?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have openerp 7 on an Ubuntu server. 
I tried to install [this module](http://thierry-godin.developpez.com/openerp/tutorial-module-creation-pos-modification-english-version/#LIX), adding it in the "addons" directory, but i can't find it in the module list of my web openerp application. (i know how to use the filters)
 
I don't want to add my modules on launchpad.
I have another question.
How to add my own modules with the openerp "official" [hosting](https://www.openerp.com/start) ? I have a free trial version.
 I tried to add my module on launchpad and i can see it on the official openerp module list (www.openerp.com/apps), but it has the community tag and i can't add any module with this tag. they don't appear on the module list of my application. How to allow them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following video and don't forget to enable Technical Features from: Settings > Users > Administrator > (edit) > Access Rights (tab).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrXrxuAKFRY